# self.context is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to call this function `domain` from my template but getting `self.context.article.domain is not a function` error. Tried looking at other answers on SO but couldn't get the issue resolved.

Here's my component-

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Article} from './Article'

@Component({
  selector:'article-art',

  template:`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 left">
        <div class="value">{{article.votes}}</div>
        <div class="label">Points</div>
      </section>
      <section class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 right">
        <a class="ui large header" href="{{ article.link }}">
          {{ article.title }}
        </a>
        <div class="meta">({{ article.domain() }})</div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href (click)="voteUp()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i>Upvote</a></li>
          <li><a href (click)="voteDown()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i>DownVote</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls:['src/article.cmponent.css']
})

export class ArticleComponent{
  @Input() article:Article;

  voteUp(){
    this.article.voteUp();
    return false;
  }

  voteDown(){
    this.article.voteDown();
    return false;
  }
  domain(): string {
 try {
 const link: string = this.link.split('//')[1];
 console.log(link);
 return link.split('/')[0];
 } catch (err) {
 return null;
 }
 }
}
```

Also attaching the reproduced problem in plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/tu7YImvsMjpWyrmjq2M2?p=preview.
You can see the errors in console.

Thanks for any help that comes my way.

Comment: Did you debug to see what exactly `self.context.article.domain` is?

Comment: @cy3er I did't get your point here. If you see the link that I have attached, you will see articles array initialized in `app.ts`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just saw that I had something missing in my code link that i shared. Updated it now.

Comment: there is no `domain` function on the `Article` class. I think you want to call `domain()` of your component instead of `article.domain()`

Comment: @yadejo Got your point. Now I added domain to my article class and it worked. Please add an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `self.context.article.domain is not a function` because there is no function called `domain` on the `Article` class. Add the `domain` function to the `Article` class and it should work as expected.